# Disable MySQL replication

Tags: mysql, replication, mysql-5.1

I'm running following:

```
# cat /etc/redhat-release 
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.6 (Santiago)
# uname -a
Linux X 2.6.32-504.3.3.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Fri Dec 12 16:05:43 EST 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
# rpm -q mysql-server
mysql-server-5.1.73-3.el6_5.x86_64
#
```

I issued `STOP SLAVE;` and deleted `master.info` and now `/var/log/mysqld-error.log` is producing following:

```
[ERROR] Error reading master configuration
[ERROR] Failed to initialize the master info structure
```

What's the proper way to disable MySQL replication?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you ran `RESET SLAVE;` make sure there is no slave status.

Run this

```
SHOW SLAVE STATUS\G
```

If there is any information still being presented, you need to run this

```
CHANGE MASTER TO master_host = '';
```

Then, go run

```
SHOW SLAVE STATUS\G
```

You should get nothing and `master.info` should be gone.

From the [MySQL 5.1 Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/reset-slave.html)

> If any startup options for setting connection parameters (such as master host, master port, master user, and master password) are in use, then any corresponding connection information stored in the master.info file is immediately reset using the values specified for these options. Options for which values are not specified are cleared. However, since these options are deprecated in MySQL 5.1 and removed altogether from MySQL 5.5, you are encouraged to use a CHANGE MASTER TO statement instead to reset the connection parameters. (If you do not use the startup options, you must issue CHANGE MASTER TO in such cases if you do not want the connection settings to be cleared.)

From the [MySQL 5.6 Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/reset-slave.html)

> Connection parameters are reset if the slave mysqld is shut down following RESET SLAVE. In MySQL 5.6.3 and later, you can instead use RESET SLAVE ALL to reset these connection parameters (Bug #11809016).

Based on this

- Note to MySQL 5.5 users: MySQL Restart is required to clear in the slave status
- Note to MySQL 5.6 users: User [RESET SLAVE ALL;](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/reset-slave.html) instead of RESET SLAVE;

Answer (score 1):

I believe, I found it)

```
mysql> RESET SLAVE;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

mysql>
```

Comment: This also solved the problem for me